# Saving an Image in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, image, system.drawing

I have a little code for saving an image from an URL in VB.NET but im not finding the location where it saves the image, i added a location string but i dont know how to use it in the code.
How do i change the location whre my code saves the    image ( Imports System.Drawing
Public Class Form1)

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim MyImage As System.Drawing.Image
    Dim URL As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim FileName As String, URLpieces As String()
    Dim location As String = "C:/SaveIMGURL/"
    URLpieces = Split(URL, "/")
    FileName = URLpieces.GetValue(UBound(URLpieces))
    MyImage = GetImage(URL)
    MyImage.Save(FileName)
    MyImage = Nothing
End Sub
Function GetImage(ByVal URL As String) As System.Drawing.Image
    Dim Request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
    Dim Response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse
    Request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URL)
    Response = CType(Request.GetResponse, System.Net.WebResponse)
    If Request.HaveResponse Then
        If Response.StatusCode = Net.HttpStatusCode.OK Then
            GetImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Response.GetResponseStream)
        End If
    End If
    Try
    Catch e As System.Net.WebException
        MsgBox("A web exception has occured [" & URL & "]." & vbCrLf & " System returned: " & e.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error!")
        Exit Try
    Catch e As System.Net.ProtocolViolationException
        MsgBox("A protocol violation has occured [" & URL & "]." & vbCrLf & "  System returned: " & e.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error!")
        Exit Try
    Catch e As System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
        MsgBox("Socket error [" & URL & "]." & vbCrLf & "  System returned: " & e.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error!")
        Exit Try
    Catch e As System.IO.EndOfStreamException
        MsgBox("An IO stream exception has occured. System returned: " & e.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error!")
        Exit Try
    Finally
    End Try
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: The image is saved in the directory the application is started from. `FileName = URLpieces.Get...` is responsible for that. You may wish to `FileName = location & URLpieces.Get...`

Comment: I just tried this, i get an this error:A generic error occurred in GDI+. Any idea why? the code is looking like this : FileName = location & URLpieces.GetValue(UBound(URLpieces))

Comment: Your application probably has no write rights in the specified directory. Or it does not exist. Try to save it to the My Documents directory and see if the general approach works.

Comment: just fixed it, thanks :)

Comment: Function checkfolder() As Integer
        If Not Directory.Exists("C:/SaveIMGURL") Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:/SaveIMGURL")           
        Else         
        End If
    End Function

Comment: Btw, that should be a `Sub` and not a `Function`.

Comment: And use `Path.Combine` instead of just `&` for a path name.